# How to count value status equal false in array object MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a JSON like this, I want to count by status false
[JSON img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMQpO.png)

```
{
  "chats": [
    {
      "memberId": "ff9e28ec-4f6f-42e2-9e66-43b888267fe5",
      "messages": [
        {
          "messagesId": "54174c03-c669-44fb-872a-75ff5c52166f",
          "user": {
            "userId": "4dd8495a-5704-435d-bee2-6b474e25cbbf",
            "name": "Event",
            "profilePicture": "png"
          },
          "createdAt": "",
          "title": "belajar",
          "image": "minio.png",
          "messages": "belajar",
          "status": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the count of all messages where status is `false`.

Example

```
{
 "memberId" : "ff9e28ec-4f6f-42e2-9e66-43b888267fe5"
 "statusCount" : 2
}
```

Comment: Is not clear what you ask . Post you code attempt ...

Comment: Is this output of any DB query . ?

Comment: So, you want to count all elements in the `messages` array with a `status` of `false`? You can't do this with a normal query. You'll need to use the aggregation pipeline, using `$unwind` to get individual messages and then perform the count manually (e.g. use `$group` with the `$sum` operator).

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('inbox').aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$chats" },
{
  "$match": {
    "chats.messages.status": false
  }
},
{ "$unwind": "$chats.messages" },
{ "$group": { 
    "_id": "$chats.memberId",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
}}])
```

I try this query and the result is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d207957e887785f2c0c745e"),
"count" : 4.0
}
```

is that something that you want?

Comment: nice,thanks a lot, im modified query like this and solve 

https://pastebin.com/RTqRJJ9k

Comment: nice to hear that. great works! seems like i have to workout about mongodb

Answer (score 1):

solve query like this

```
db.inbox.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$chats" },
{ $unwind: "$chats.messages" },
{
  $match: {
    "chats.messages.status": false
  }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: { inboxId: "$inboxId", memberId: "$chats.memberId" },
            count: { $sum :1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {inboxId : '$_id.inboxId', memberId : '$_id.memberId', count : '$count', _id : 0}

    }

])
```